# Help with Categories in Lean

Tags: category-theory, computer-assisted-proofs

I'm looking to start a project on categories in Lean. I was wondering if anyone could help me out with finding a few of the basic constructions... maybe you know where to look.

I'd like to be able to:

1. Create a category given a type for the objects, morphisms, etc. (or some variation of this)
2. Create the opposite category
3. Product and internal hom of categories
4. Isomorphism classes of natural transformations.
5. Simplicial C w/ for a category C
6. Full subcategory consisting of objects matching a certain condition
7. Equalizer and coequilizer of functors.

Comment: You should say that Lean is a [proof assistant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lean_(proof_assistant)).

Comment: I'm glad you asked, because I'd never heard of Lean, and having googled a bit it looks worth a look if I'm ever looking for such things. My guess is it's an excellent choice for this project. If I were you, having decided on Lean my next step would be to learn some Lean, starting with whatever the standard tutorials start with, instead of trying to start with my project. Could be that knowing how the platform works would make the answers to my questions clear - since at some point I imagine I will be learning how it works why not start there? https://leanprover.github.io/about/

Comment: This will almost certainly get a better answer faster on the new [proof assistant se](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/), where many lean experts hang out

Comment: I'll have to take your advice! @DavidC.Ullrich Lean is considered by most to have the best community. I consider it to be the best design because of how it can handle quotients where Coq and others cannot (somehow you can't mod out by an equivalence relation and you need "setoids". This has been given the name "setoid hell").